# Plot RGB values for each feature seperately

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, rgb

I want to plot each rgb value for its respective feature of the layer via pyqgis. Atm I struggle to properly implement it for each layer individually. With my current code below, all features get the last color code in row no.3. and therefore they all have the same color instead of every element ist individual one.

I use QGIS 2.8.8 Wien and therefore proposed solutions for QGIS 3 do not work properly.

```
b = iface.activeLayer()

symbols = b.rendererV2().symbols()
symbol = symbols[0]
            
for f in b.getFeatures():
    expr = f['rgb']
    express = "color_rgb("+str(expr) +")"
    symbol.symbolLayer(0).setDataDefinedProperty('color', express)

b.triggerRepaint()
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(b)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please consider updating to the latest LTR. I doubt there are people around who could help you, who still have access to 2.8.

Comment: You are 100% right but unfortunately the code was preproduced by another guy who never updated to newer versions. I would have never implemented it into 2.8 myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code i adapted for you, it worked on my qgis 2.18.28:

```
b = iface.activeLayer()

fni = b.fieldNameIndex("rgb")
unique_values = b.uniqueValues(fni)

# fill categories
categories = []
for unique_value in unique_values:
    red, blue, green = unique_value.split(",")
    # initialize the default symbol for this geometry type
    symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(b.geometryType())
    symbol.setSize(size)
    # configure a symbol layer
    layer_style = {}
    layer_style['color'] = '%d, %d, %d' % (red, blue, green)
    layer_style['outline'] = '#000000'
    symbol_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2.create(layer_style)

    # replace default symbol layer with the configured one
    if symbol_layer is not None:
        symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)

    # create renderer object
    category = QgsRendererCategoryV2(unique_value, symbol, str(unique_value))
    # entry for the list of category items
    categories.append(category)

# create renderer object
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2('$id', categories)

# assign the created renderer to the layer
if renderer is not None:
    b.setRendererV2(renderer)
b.triggerRepaint()


b.triggerRepaint()
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(b)
```